# How to integrate different data struct into one ? Any design pattern or exprience?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, data-structures, struct, architecture

As you know, different vendor may have different name of data field. Although the name is difference, the data struct is almost the same. 
For example,

```
struct s1 {
    int s1Price,
    int s1Volume
};


struct s2 {
    int s2Price,
    int s2Volume
};
```

Like stock market data, the data would sent to program automatically, and the program just receives the data and then processes it.

I want to design a program which can easily change to other vendor's data struct.

If I develop program with `s1`, sometime later, I want to change to `s2` with smallest change.

I hope you can get my point.

Could you give me any advice ? Any design patter or your experience ?

Comment: The keyword here is that the structures are *similar*, being similar means that they're not the same. Even if they look the same, doesn't mean they are handled the same or even that you see the full structure.Don't try to "integrate" different structures into one, unless it is *your own* structures in *your own* code.

Comment: You may wrap that into your own structure, so you only have to change your wrapper class at one place when you change.

Comment: You write an abstraction on top of it and use that abstraction in your program.

Comment: Proxy them via your own interface. Only use your own interface in your code.

Comment: And now you've had three comments in a row that describe the same thing using different terms. At least one of them should sound familiar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword here is **abstraction**.

Here is one way of doing it :

```
#include <iostream>

struct s1 {
  int s1Price;
  int s1Volume;
};


struct s2 {
  int s2Price;
  int s2Volume;
};

class   Idata
{
public:
  virtual ~Idata() {}

public:
  virtual int   getPrice() = 0;
  virtual int   getVolume() = 0;
};

class s1Data : public Idata, public s1 {
public:
  s1Data(const s1& S1) : s1(S1) {}

  virtual int   getPrice() {
    return s1Price;
  }

  virtual int   getVolume() {
    return s1Volume;
  }
};

class s2Data : public Idata, public s2 {
public:
  s2Data(const s2& S2) : s2(S2) {}

  virtual int   getPrice() {
    return s2Price;
  }

  virtual int   getVolume() {
    return s2Volume;
  }
};


void    my_func_that_will_never_change_because_it_uses_abstraction(Idata *data)
{
  std::cout << data->getPrice() << std::endl;
  std::cout << data->getVolume() << std::endl;
}

int     main(void)
{
  s1    Sfirst{42, 21};
  s2    Ssecond{99, 88};

  s1Data        DataFirst(Sfirst);
  s2Data        DataSecond(Ssecond);

  my_func_that_will_never_change_because_it_uses_abstraction(&DataFirst);
  my_func_that_will_never_change_because_it_uses_abstraction(&DataSecond);
}
```

Code all your program the same way `my_func_that_will_never_change_because_it_uses_abstraction` is coded (by using the interface `IData` not the concrete underlying types) and you'll have nothing to change except the initialisation phase which determine which type of data you will have in the first place.

Comment: This does help me. What I think before is just write a converter to convert to my own data struct. Thanks.